# Spring @Autowired annotated object value is null

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

// My Factory class

```
@Component
public class UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory {

    @Autowired
    private VirginAmericaValidator virginAmericaValidator;

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        static UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory instance = new UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory();
    }

    public static UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.instance;
    }

    private UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory() {}

    public PartnerValidator getPartnerValidator(Partner partner){
            return virginAmericaValidator;
    }
}
```

// My Validator class

```
@Service
public class VirginAmericaValidator implements PartnerValidator {

    @Override
    public void validate(String code) throws InvalidCodeException{
        //do some processing if processing fails throw exception
        if (code.equals("bad".toString())){
            throw new InvalidCodeException();
        }
    }
}
```

//Usage:

```
    PartnerValidator pv = UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory.getInstance().getPartnerValidator(partner);
    if (pv != null){
        try {
            pv.validate(userRewardAccount);
        } catch (InvalidCodeException e){
            return buildResponse(ResponseStatus.INVALID_USER_REWARD_ACCOUNT, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My package scan level is at much higher level. Whats happening is my virginAmericaValidator is always empty. Why is @Autowired annotation not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current approach will not work with Spring as you are ultimately using `new UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory` to create the instance which essentially bypasses Spring context altogether. Two approaches that should possibly work are these:

a. Using a `factory-method` and using xml to define your bean:

```
<bean class="package.UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory" name="myfactory" factory-method="getInstance"/>
```

This will essentially return the instance that you are creating back as a Spring bean and should get autowired cleanly.

b. Using Java `@Configuration` based mechanism:

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfiguration {
   @Bean 
   public UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory myFactory() {
       return UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory.getInstance();
   }
}
```

Comment: or c) using @Configurable and AspectJ, then Spring inject even in Instances that are created by `new` (I mention this only for completes, and because to fight against this rumor that Spring can not inject in classes that are generated by `new` - because it is wrong)

Comment: If I make VirginAmericaValidator extend from another abstract class and implement interface there, will that make spring autowire for me?

Comment: No, that also will not work as the issue is still in the way `UserRewardAccountValidatorFactory` is created, not in the Validator. You should be able to get it working with one of the two options that I have mentioned. Approach that Ralph mentioned is also great, but it will require full AspectJ weaving to get it to work.